# Advanced parameters for Realtek PCI-e GBE family network card

Tags: windows, networking

I have opened properties for this network card and advanced tab there. There are lots of parameters, where can I obtain explanations about each of them?
 [image]

Comment: Even more complete description in:

http://superuser.com/questions/853500/optimal-setting-for-advanced-parameters-for-realtek-pci-e-gbe-family-network-car

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would start with network card manual.

If you can't find one, using google for each is good way to find answers. Here's answers for the list shown in the screenshot:

- **Auto Disable Gigabit**: running on gigabit speed consumes more power. This option automatically disables it when there is no need for faster connection.
- **Flow Control**: Flow Control is mechanism for handling send/receive speeds without outrunning slower party
- **Green Ethernet**: Proprietary power saving technology
- **Interrupt Moderation**: no interrupt for every packet, but after timeout/enough data. For busy networks, this will lower the load, but increase latencies.
- **IPv4 Checksum Offload**: Network controller will calculate checksums, instead of CPU.
- **Jumbo Frame**: support for larger frames than ethernet default (1500 bytes)
- **Large Send Offload**: method for sending large amount of data to network controller, which will then process it at once
- **Network Address**: most probably MAC address of network card.
- **Priority & VLAN**: priority: QoS feature. [VLAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_LAN): Virtual LAN
- **Receive Buffers**: Size of buffers for received data. Larger buffer obviously consumes more resources, but smaller buffer might block (drop) traffic on a busy network.
- **Receive Side Scaling**: support for using multiple processor while receiving
- **Shutdown Wake-On-Lan**: Enable wake-on-lan support (possibility to remotely start up computer with special network packet)
- **Speed & Duplex**: default speed (for example 10Mb/s, 100Mb/s) and duplex (half- or full-)